# Getting 0 as result when float contains equation

Tags: c, floating-point

I'm trying to write a very simple program that converts quarts of water (user input) to molecules of water in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

int main(void)
{
    float water_quarts;
    float water_grams = (water_quarts*950.00);
    float water_molecules = (water_grams/3e-23F);


    printf("Enter an amount of water in quarts: \n");
    scanf("%f", &water_quarts );
    printf("%f quarts is %f grams of water.\n", water_quarts, water_grams );
    printf("%f grams is %f molecules of water.\n", water_grams, water_molecules );

    return 0;
}
```

However, when I compile and run it, it gives me:

```
Enter an amount of water in quarts: 
15
15.000000 quarts is 0.000000 grams of water.
0.000000 grams is 0.000000 molecules of water.
```

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm using gcc 4.9.1 on lubuntu 14.10, running through VirtualBox.

Comment: you have to calculate `water_grams` and `water_molecules` after setting `water_quarts` and not before.

Comment: doing the calculation even before you get the operand values won't help you. shouldn't it be in the other direction?

Answer (score 5):

Your need to assign values to `water_grams` and `water_molecules` after you take input for `water_quarts` from the user ( that is after your `scanf()` ).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

int main(void)
{
    float water_quarts;
    printf("Enter an amount of water in quarts: \n");
    scanf("%f", &water_quarts );

    float water_grams = (water_quarts*950.00);
    float water_molecules = (water_grams/3e-23F);

    printf("%f quarts is %f grams of water.\n", water_quarts, water_grams );
    printf("%f grams is %f molecules of water.\n", water_grams, water_molecules );

    return 0;
}
```

or alternatively

```
float water_quarts;
float water_grams ;
float water_molecules ;


printf("Enter an amount of water in quarts: \n");
scanf("%f", &water_quarts );
water_grams  = (water_quarts*950.00);
water_molecules  = (water_grams/3e-23F);
```

Otherwise, you are assigning uninitialized values to them, which is why you are getting unexpected output.

When you declare a variable, it will have some garbage value ( unless you assign it some value ), and due to that, when you do

```
float water_grams = (water_quarts*950.00);
float water_molecules = (water_grams/3e-23F);
```

`water_quarts` has some garbage value, and thus, you are just assigning some garbage to the other variables.